# ASP.NET MVC - French/Spanish accent not correctly displayed

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, utf-8, iis-7

I'm working on multilingual website where I want to get language resource from SQL db table. Resource Table column is already set to **nvarchar** though It's completely strange behavior get junk character when it's getting rendered in MVC View.

```
û rendered as Ã»
```

However, It's working fine in my local machine but problem occurs on production environment only. Don't know why!!!
Static & Resource file content of different languages are rendered perfectly fine but the problem occurs only for resources retrieved from SQL table.

Tried setting meta tag with utf-8 charset in page & globalization with request response encoding to utf-8 in web.config but couldn't resolve my problem.

Should it be problem of IIS or Entity Framework is converting it to junk characters? Really confused.....
I'm using MVC4 with Entity Framework.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked the database collation?

Comment: It's SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS.

Comment: Test the app in your local environment using the production database, is it possible?

Comment: @Fabio Luz : I have already shared same database in both local and production environment for testing purpose.

Comment: I see, so the problem might be the IIS. Is the data being serialized in JSON or something else?

Comment: No it's pure MVC with EF to fetch data nd build model to pass on View.